# How to use muliple variables in same function

Tags: jquery

What is the proper way to combine multiple variables

I tried this but didn't work.

```
varONE = "td.class1";
varTWO = "td.class2";

$('table').find(varONE,varTWO).css('background', 'red');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you actually need to set the selectors the jquery way, for example

```
varONE = $("td.class1");
varTWO = $("td.class2");

$('table').find(varONE,varTWO).css('background', 'red');
```

Then your script will work.

You can also use a concatenated string

```
varONE = "td.class1";
varTWO = "td.class2";

$('table').find(varONE + "," + varTWO).css('background', 'red');
```

And it will also work. I recommend you the first solution as it is cleaner, but you can choose.

Comment: @MShack You need to invoke those functions to return the results. `$('.two_column_layout').find(getPlayerByeQuery() + ',' + getPlayerQuery()).css('background', 'red');` - Works just fine.

Comment: ty , forgot the () aside each one

Answer (score 3):

You need the comma in the string itself like

```
$('table').find('td.class1,td.class2').css('background', 'red');
```

or

```
varONE = "td.class1";
varTWO = "td.class2";

$('table').find(varONE+','+varTWO).css('background', 'red');
```

The only overloads for [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) are a `selector`(*string*) or an *element*. However, there isn't an overload which accepts multiple `selectors`(*stings*) as separate **parameters**

Answer (score 1):

same as concatenating strings

```
$('table').find(varONE + ',' + varTWO).css('background', 'red');
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, the `.find` method doesn't take multiple selector strings.

If you want to use `.find` in that way, you could create your own method.

```js
$.fn.argfind = function () {
  return this.find(Array.prototype.join.call(arguments));
};

var one = "td.class1",
    two = "td.class2";

$('table').argfind(one, two).css('background', 'red');
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="class1">Example</td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Example</td>
    <td class="class2">Text</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```